# Props component in Field redux-form don't works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a simple component for rendering an `input`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class TextInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const { placeholder } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="input"
          placeholder={placeholder}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

TextInput.propTypes = {
  meta: PropTypes.shape({}),
  placeholder: PropTypes.string
};

export default TextInput;
```

And I have a form who render my input with `Field` component from `redux-form`

Like that :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  Field,
  reduxForm
} from 'redux-form';

import TextInput from '../../Fields/TextInput/index';

import {
  USERNAME_NAME_FIELD,
  PASSWORD_NAME_FIELD
} from '../../../constants/strings';

class LoginPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};

    this.showResults = this.showResults.bind(this);
  }

  showResults(values) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(values);
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="loginPage">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.showResults)} className="loginPage__form">
          <div className="loginPage__form__fields">
            <Field
              name={USERNAME_NAME_FIELD}
              type="text"
              component={TextInput}
              label={USERNAME_NAME_FIELD}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="loginPage__form__fields">
            <Field
              name={PASSWORD_NAME_FIELD}
              type="text"
              component={TextInput}
              label={USERNAME_NAME_FIELD}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="loginPage__form__fields">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

LoginPage.propTypes = {
  values: PropTypes.shape({}),
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func
};


export default reduxForm({
  form: 'loginPage' // a unique identifier for this form
})(LoginPage);
```

And I can't get the values when I passed my own component, but if I remove my own component and I replace it with a `input` string, he works and I can get my values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample code, you're not passing `placeholder` prop. But then, you're asking about `value`. Assuming you're asking about how to pass `value` and other HTML attributes such as `placeholder`, the answer can be found in their [docs](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/field.md/#props).

> Any custom props passed to Field will be merged into the props object on the same level as the input and meta objects.

`value` is part of `input` object, and other HTML attributes such as `placeholder` are at same level as `input`. I know it's confusing as hell and it took me a long while to wrap my head around it.

So to get the value, you would use:

```
const { placeholder, input: { value } } = this.props;
```

And to pass `placeholder`:

```
<Field
  name={USERNAME_NAME_FIELD}
  type="text"
  component={TextInput}
  label={USERNAME_NAME_FIELD}
  placeholder="some placeholder text"
/>
```

Also, your input `type` is not a valid type. It should be `type="text"` (judging from your code). You can see a list of valid input types [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Form_%3Cinput%3E_types).